# How to maximize a view in sublime 2 layouts?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually work with 4 views (grid) in a layout.

Sometimes, I want them to be maximized so the text is visible.

Using the mouse, is a no-go because I have my hands stuck to the keyboard.

so I want with a keyboard shortcut to maximize the space of the view.

this is how the layout looks like now

[image: from]

and here is how I want it to be after using the shortcut.

[image: to]

Any ideas? (keep in mind that I want to use the same shortcut, so pressing ctrl+alt+1 to maximize the 1st etc, is not an option)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The [MaxPane](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/MaxPane) package enables a **single keyboard shortcut** (by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to **maximize** the active view and also **restore** it, if it is maximized.

It will however completely **hide the inactive views** when the active view is maximized, unlike as shown in your second screenshot.

There are two modes:

- maximize **focus** group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> where you can see the tabs, files sidebar and application menu as if you have only one focus group
- **maximize** actual editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> where you can see only actual open editor (somehow similar to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd> distraction free mode)

The both shortcuts work as on/off switch.

MaxPane is also sublimetext3 compatible.

Comment: Exactly what i need, no hustle, just toggle with the shortcut maximize view and return to normal

Answer (score 5):

You will want to install the [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) package.

The shortcut <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> will zoom the current view to 90% of the full page size.

Pressing <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> will return to the normal sizes of your open panes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not want to install the origami package, allthough it is a great plugin.

I just need a command like this packages "zoom_pane", but I know nothing about pyhton.

Comment: Thanks for this - exactly what I wanted! ...back to happy coding.

Comment: **NOTE: The following keyboard shortcuts for zooming and editing pane sizes are not enabled by default due to a conflict with built-in ST features. Open the Preferences: Origami Key Bindings from the Command Palette to enable or edit them, or just use the Command Palette to trigger those commands.**

Comment: Coming back here almost a year later after upgrading to a M1 MacBook and just wanted to say thank you past-self for making this comment.